# In localhost it's still showing the lowest version using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lampp, php-7.2

I have updated my PHP version to `7.2` in my Ubuntu machine. I am getting this version while running this `php -v` command in my terminal and getting the below output.

```
PHP 7.2.1-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan 11 2018 22:52:58) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.1-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I am running localhost file `localhost/test/common.php` the lower version is coming.

common.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

the above file is giving the below output.

```
PHP Version 5.6.23
System  Linux subrajyoti-H81M-S 3.13.0-139-generic #188-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 14:43:09 UTC 2018 x86_64
Build Date  Jun 24 2016 15:40:58
```

I am running this file via `lampp`. But here it is showing me the lower php version (`i.e - 5.6.23`). I need here to upgrade the php version also.

Comment: Hi satya. You're still adding "please help" messages to your questions, which is the kind of chatty material that we tend to remove here. Native English speakers may interpret it as a form of begging, especially given how impatient some question authors are on Stack Overflow. Please refrain from adding this to your material, so that the work done by volunteer editors can be reduced a little.

Comment: In addition, I notice a number of your questions where you seem to have attracted good-quality answers, but you seem to have been too busy to vote, accept or comment-reply to that assistance. While those things are not strictly mandatory on Stack Overflow, basic manners are (obviously) still desirable.