# Could not connect to phpMyAdmin using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect `database` using PHP and Apache2 server but it could not connect. I am providing my code below.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['start'] = time();
$_SESSION['show_session_alert'] = 1;

$VIEW_ADMIN = 1;
$VIEW_OWNER = 2;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "abcdefg");
mysql_select_db('easyride', $con);

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "abcdefg", "easyride");
?>
```

I am trying to connect to MySQL database but it could not connected. I am giving below the phpMyAdmin configuration file.

> /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php:

```
$dbuser='phpmyadmin';
$dbpass='abcdefg';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='';
$dbport='';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

Here I am unable to connect getting the error `localhost is currently unable to handle this request: HTTP ERROR 500`. I need to connect to my MySQL database.

Comment: why you are using mysql and mysqli on same file

Comment: Ok let me to keep any one and check .

Comment: As the other comment says, why is there a mysqli and mysql connection together. Does not make much sense. Try to remove one or the other and check for yourself if it works. It might be a connection error most probably. I had the same error message yesterday but with different problem. So it should be the connection.

Comment: Ok let me get this correct, the first snippet is your server code right ? and the one below is the config file for phpmyadmin. Both could have different reasons for not being able to connect to the DB, your PHP file is attempting two different ways to connect to the db as mentioned above, and PHPmyadmin could fail for many reasons, fixing one will not probably fix the other issue as well. Btw, Check if you have included PHPmyadmin's config file in apache's config file

Comment: what is the php version? Remember to @Niner me if you want more help or ping others.

Comment: Never mind the above, seeing your past question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48319731/ is php 7. The mysql_ api was deleted in that version.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are using some version of php7, in this case the functions mysql_connect and mysql_select_db no longer exists in php7 so they will not work

Comment: If he is using PHP7, and then there aren't the mysql_* functions, an `FATAL ERROR` would be raised! So, this is not that case.

Comment: @user2342558 This answer is in fact correct. See the OP's previous question, and as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338141/could-not-connect-to-phpmyadmin-using-php-and-mysql?noredirect=1#comment83665006_48338141) I left under the post.

Comment: ok, I understand.